# Sox is splitting audio file a little too early

Tags: audio, mp3, wav, sox, libsox

I am splitting an audio file with sox and it works reasonably well with these settings:

```
sox in.wav out5.wav silence -l 1 0.1 1% 1 0.5 1% : newfile : restart
```

However, it often cuts just a little bit too early at the beginning, meaning that the beginning of the first word is slightly cut in. Is there a way to tell sox too start cutting a few milliseconds earlier?